# Enviar um SMS a um dos contactos

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Tenho uma aplicação e no fim queria mandar uma *msg* a um dos contactos do utilizador sobre a minha aplicação.

```
var columnNumber = cursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number);
            contacto_numero = cursor.GetString(columnNumber);         
            SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(contacto_numero, null,msg_texto, null, null);
```

Este é o meu código, e não percebo o porque de não mandar *msg* nenhuma, acho que tenho tudo em condições.

A minha *msg* é assim e nao tem mais de 160 caracteres..

```
msg_texto= "O seu amigo " + user_nome + " recomendoou a vir fazer o nosso questionario, venha experirmentar a nossa aplicação. Procure-nos na Playstore";
```

Agradeco muito a quem puder ajudar

Comment: lembra-se de que, se usar unicode `ç` e/ou `ã`, vai ser bem mais pesada. Por exemplo, mandando `O seu amigo recomendoou a vir fazer o nosso questionario, venha experirmentar a nossa aplicação. Procure-nos na Playstore` use-se 121 caracteres em duas mensagens, enquanto `O seu amigo recomendoou a vir fazer o nosso questionario, venha experirmentar a nossa aplicacao. Procure-nos na Playstore` (sem o çã) usa 120 em apenas uma mensagem. Por que? Por causa do *encoding* da mensagem necessário para usar esses caracteres.

Comment: Pode visualizar o que estou falando [usando esse site aqui](https://messente.com/documentation/sms-length-calculator), e digitando sua mensagem, vendo a diferença entre usar `çã` e `ca`

Answer (score -2):

isso vai depender do provedor usado para SMS.
sugiro que use uma dos seguintes serviços: Twilio, Infobip, MARKTEL, Zenvia e LocaSMS.
Esses serviços são pagos e possuem API bem simples de implementar.